# How to use a volume label in a Windows path?

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup, volumes

I want to copy files off a removable drive using a batch file, regardless of the drive letter it gets.

So far, no go. There don't seem to be any readily available commands or 3rd-party command-line tools that would handle paths based on volume labels.

I tried FreeFileSync, but it works in big batches, and I need precise file operations here. Also, it doesn't do deletions, and I need to MOVE files off the pendrive.

What piques my interest, however, is that issuing a nonsense command like...

```
C:\> cd MYPENDRIVE:
```

... results in quite an interesting bit in the default error message:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If this message is to be trusted, then it means there IS some correct syntax for putting a volume label in there. Or isn't there?

Note: I can settle for writing a small "getdriveletterforvolume" tool, if I have to, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel. Also, during longer batch file operations the drive may be removed and replaced with another, at which point I'll need the operations to cease, and not continue on another drive that gets the same drive letter.

Note2: Using \\?\Volume{12345678.....} is a last resort, though it can be tamed to some extent, to build a rudimentary batch file like...

```
SET PENDRIVE=\\?\Volume{949a764e-a2f0-11e3-b710-6cf04975450b}
SET BACKUPDRIVE=\\?\Volume{e79091c4-5c2a-11e3-86f9-806e6f6e6963}

if exist %PENDRIVE% {
  if exist %BACKUPDRIVE% {
    move %PENDRIVE%\*.* %BACKUPDRIVE%
  }
}
```

... but it's ugly and doesn't let me do any magic like giving two pendrives the same label to have them behave identically. I know it's not a common case, but hey, why limit one's options where there might be a ready solution?

---

Edit: Progress. I modified the subroutine to return a value as VOLUMEID:

```
CALL :GetVolumeID PENDRIVE
SET "PENDRIVE=%VOLUMEID%"
IF EXIST "%PENDRIVE%\" ECHO PENDRIVE is connected at %PENDRIVE%!

GOTO :eof

:GetVolumeID
FOR /F "skip=1" %%A in ('"wmic volume where label='%~1' get deviceid 2>/null"') do (
 SET "VOLUMEID=%%A"
 GOTO :eof
)
GOTO :eof
```

... but now if the pendrive is missing, `wmic` returns some empty-like value (NOT an empty string; it fails an `if %%A==""` check) - and so `IF EXIST \` ends up true. How do I eliminate an empty result like that..? I tried `SET VOLUMEID=$FOO$` before the `FOR`, but it overwrites that with an empty value anyway.

---

Finally! Here's a proof of concept, for whomever finds it useful.

```
@ECHO OFF

CALL :GetVolumeID BACKUPDRIVE
SET "BACKUPDRIVE=%VOLUMEID%"

CALL :GetVolumeID PENDRIVE
SET "PENDRIVE=%VOLUMEID%"

if exist %PENDRIVE%\ (
    if exist %BACKUPDRIVE%\ (

        echo Emptying the pendrive.

        move %PENDRIVE%\*.* %BACKUPDRIVE%\pendrive\
    )
)

GOTO :eof

:GetVolumeID
SET VOLUMEID=$$$
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A IN ('"wmic volume where label='%~1' get deviceid /value 2>nul"') DO  IF NOT "%%~B"=="" SET "VOLUMEID=%%~B"
SET "VOLUMEID=%VOLUMEID:~0,-2%"
GOTO :eof
```

I added the $ bogus value to be returned to fail an EXIST check.
The final SET VOLUMEID=%VOLUMEID... line removes the trailing backslash (for some reason it counts as TWO characters) so that paths written as `%MYDRIVE%\file*.*` look sane.

Comment: I modified @npocmaka 's suggestion, to return a value (sort of). It still has an issue, though, erasing that value when no matching drive is found.

This is now a purely `cmd` problem, as the volume-label-related part is solved.

Comment: Use the **`/value`** option with wmic to solve the empty string issue. **`FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A in ('"wmic volume where label='%~1' get deviceid /value 2>nul"') do if not "%%~B"=="" SET "VOLUMEID=%%~B"`**

Comment: Great. I didn't realize ( ) blocks change variable scope... somehow. In parantheses, it doesn't work at all. Without them, it does...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a final proof of concept, for whomever finds it useful. Calling GetVolumeID sets a DRIVELETTER variable as return, in the "F:" form.

```
@ECHO OFF

CALL :GetVolumeID BACKUPDRIVE
SET "BACKUPDRIVE=%DRIVELETTER%"

CALL :GetVolumeID PENDRIVE
SET "PENDRIVE=%DRIVELETTER%"

if exist %PENDRIVE%\ (
    if exist %BACKUPDRIVE%\ (

        echo Emptying the pendrive.

        move %PENDRIVE%\*.* %BACKUPDRIVE%\pendrive\
    )
)

GOTO :eof

:GetVolumeID
SET DRIVELETTER=$$$
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims==" %%A IN ('"wmic volume where label='%~1' get deviceid /value 2>nul"') DO  IF NOT "%%~B"=="" SET "DRIVELETTER=%%~B"
SET "DRIVELETTER=%DRIVELETTER:~0,-2%"
GOTO :eof
```

Answer (score 2):

here's a subroutine that will `push` you to a drive by its name.It takes one argument - the drive label:

```
@echo off

:pushToLabel label 

setlocal
for /f "skip=1 delims=:" %%A in ('"wmic logicaldisk where VolumeName='%~1' get name"') do (
 set "drive=%%A:"

 goto :break
)
:break
echo %drive%
endlocal && (
    pushd %drive%
)
```

Comment: Would recommend `wmic volume where label='%~1' get name` to support drives that are mounted as NTFS folders as well.  I add this because OPs original question asked about running out of drive letters.

Comment: Interesting. I'd modify it to use `wmic volume where label='%~1' get deviceid` instead, and just use the device for copy/move/xcopy commands, as that does work, and I don't strictly need to `cd`/`pushd` there, especially if the volume may (in an extreme case) not even HAVE a drive letter assigned. Your suggestion does take a bit of horror out from my \\?\Volume... approach, though.

Comment: I don't think `pushd` will accept a 'name' gotten from `wmic` in the \\?\Volume{...} format.

Comment: @SinusMackowaty  Correct, if the drive does not have either a drive letter or a NTFS folder mount point, then the name will be `\\?\Volume{GUID}\ ` and `pushd` does not support those paths.  `pushd` would only work if it was a drive letter or a NTFS folder mount point.