# Path with volume/drive label instead of letter

Tags: windows, cmd

I have a volume `E:` that has a label `Data` applied to it.

When specifying paths, following works:

`E:/some/path/to/sub/folder`

Is it possible to refer to the volume by its label, instead of letter? I.e. something like:

`/Data/some/path/to/sub/folder`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a volume label in a Windows path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325246/how-to-use-a-volume-label-in-a-windows-path)

Comment: Not directly.  One obvious reason why not is that there is nothing preventing two or more volumes having the same label.